# How to align a <p> into <div> or <td> when content it is dynamic?

Tags: html, css

I have a problema when I try to center a `<p>` tag into `<td>` for example. I know that I must use the following:

```
Width:80%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

But the problem comes when the content of the `<p>` is dynamic.
Maybe one day the content is a single sentence like "Hello Michael" but the next day it is "Today it is a very good day" as you can see the second sentence is longer than the first one and then the css used is not the correct basically for the width value choosen...

How can I fix that thing?

Comment: To start with, margin: 0px auto is more correct (though yours mostly works). Secondly, it works for me within a table cell and I don't see why it shouldn't work within a div. Setting the para width forces it into an inline-block and the margin settings should center it - unless there's something you're not telling us about the table cell formatting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the paragraph `display:inline-block` and add `text-align:center` to the parent `td`.

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, adipisci!</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For aligning text in the center, you should use `text-align: center;`
Since

is a block-level element, it is unable to set its margin left and right automatically.